# How to extend the django-comments model

Tags: python, django, extend

(Sorry for my bad english, i'm a shabby French)

I try to extend the django comment framework to add a like/dislike system.
After read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/comments/custom/#an-example-custom-comments-app), i have added this to my **model.py** :

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class Commentslikes(Comment):
    positif = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    negatif = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After launch the command `python manage.py syncdb`, django have created the **commentslikes** mysql table with 3 cols : *comment_ptr_id*, *positif*, *negatif* . It's ok.

In my **view.py** file, i have override the comment post view with this :

```
   def custom_comment_post(request, next=None, using=None):

        #Post the comment and get the response
        response = contrib_comments.post_comment(request, next, using)

        if type(response) == HttpResponseRedirect:
           redirect_path, comment_id = response.get('Location').split( '?c=' )
           if comment_id:
                comment = Comment.objects.get( id=comment_id )
                if comment:

               #For test, i try to add 20 positif likes, 10 dislikes and edit the comment with 'foo'
                comment.positif = 20
                comment.negatif = 10
                comment.comment = 'foo'
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect( redirect_path + "#c" + comment_id)
       return response
```

Then I posted a test comment. Comment has been modified with 'foo' but no rows have been added in the **commentslikes** table with the id of comment, positif at 20 and negatif at 10. Not row for the comment has added in **commentslikes**

I have forgotten or done something ?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Bonjour! Just to let you know, I was with one of the core contributors to Django last week, and he mentioned it is probably best not to use Django's comments, as they're likely to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Thomas,

well you've extended Comment with Commentslikes so you probably want to use that class "Commentslikes" in your view; not "Comment".

Side notes:

- it's usually better to avoid plural in Model class names and better to use camel case.
- you could use composition instead.